How to calibrate and simulate a copula-garch model in R using rmgarch package
So I have been trying to calibrate and simulate cryptocurrencies for VaR and ES analysis using the rmgarch package in R. I have been using the t-copula, my reason being that cryptocurrencies' volatility does not decrease when their value increases - their rally up as fast as they rally downwards. Thus, it makes more sense to use a distribution with fat tails that is symmetrical.
The issue I have is that after fitting to the data using cgarchfit(), running a simulation using cgarchsim(), I am unable to extract the calibrated degrees of freedom, $\nu$, which is required for the student-t copula. I have been using cgarchfit()@model$fit$df.residual to try and extract the degrees of freedom, but it always returns NULL.
Additionally, what is the functional difference between forecast and sim? I know for forecast, if we have 100 observations, we can use 80 observations and test if our model can replicate the 100. But what about if we want to extend this for 300 observations, outside of the realm of our dataset. Is there any difference?
My code is as follows:
require(copula)
require(rugarch)
library(dplyr)
require(rmgarch)


data <- read.csv('returns_data.csv')
tickers <- c('ETH.USD', 'BTC.USD', 'XRP.USD', 'LTC.USD',...more coins)

data <- data[,tickers]
d = length(tickers)


# Here I have imported the appropriate ARMA-Garch parameters. They are all GARCH(1,1), but some are ARMA(1,1), (1,0), etc (all max lag 1). 

ARMA_GARCH_lags <- read.csv('ARMA_GARCH_lags.csv')
specs <- vector("list", d)

for (i in 1:d) {
  ticker <- tickers[i]
  ARMA_order <- as.numeric(ARMA_GARCH_lags[[ticker]][1:2])
  GARCH_order<- as.numeric(ARMA_GARCH_lags[[ticker]][3:4])

  specs[[i]] <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(garchOrder = GARCH_order, model = "sGARCH"),
                           mean.model = list(armaOrder = ARMA_order, include.mean = FALSE),
                           distribution.model = "std"
                           )
}

multispec <- multispec(specs)

c_spec <- cgarchspec(multispec, VAR = FALSE, robust = FALSE, lag = 1, lag.max = NULL, asymmetric = FALSE,
                     lag.criterion = c("AIC"), external.regressors = NULL, dccOrder = c(0, 0), 
                     distribution.model = list(copula = c("mvt"), method = c("ML"),time.varying = FALSE,
                                               transformation = c("parametric")))
 

c_fit <- cgarchfit(c_spec, data2, fit.control = list(eval.se = TRUE, stationarity = TRUE, scale = TRUE),
                   solver = "nlminb", solver.control = list(), out.sample = 0,
                   cluster = NULL, VAR.fit = FALSE, realizedVol = NULL)

print(c_fit@model$fit$df.residual)    # This always prints NULL.



Msims <- 2000
Nsteps <- 365

c_sim <-  cgarchsim(c_fit, n.sim = Nsteps, n.start = 0, m.sim = Msims, startMethod = c("sample"),
                    presigma = NULL, preresiduals = NULL, prereturns = NULL, preR = NULL,
                    preQ = NULL, preZ = NULL, rseed = NULL, mexsimdata = NULL, vexsimdata = NULL,
                    cluster = NULL, only.density = FALSE, prerealized = NULL)


observations <- c_sim@msim$simX

# START SIMULATION USING observations


loss_function <- c()

for (M in 1:Msims){
  X <- observations[[M]] 
  
  V_0 <- starting_positions 
  S <- starting_prices
  
  S <- S + S * colSums(X)

  V_f = S * starting_units
  
  PnL = sum(- (V_f - V_0))
  loss_function <- append(loss_function, PnL)s
  
  
}


mu = mean(loss_function)
sigma = sd(loss_function)

VaR_levels <- c(0.95, 0.99)

nu <- 4.5   # Some arbitrary value as I am unable to extract the calibrated value from the fit

iCDF_t <- qt(p=VaR_levels, df=nu) 
VaR <- mu + sigma * iCDF_t
ES <- mu + sigma * dt( df=nu, iCDF_t  )/ (1-VaR_levels) * ( (nu + iCDF_t^2) / (nu - 1))

print(ES)

